# Livewire: Unable to call component method. Public method [childMethodName] not found on component: [parent]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Using Laravel Livewire, I have a parent and a (repeating) child. The child blade has a call to `childMethod()` through `wire:click="childMethod()"`.

The problem is that `parent->childMethod()` is called while I wanted `child->childMethod()` to be called.

The parent component

```
class StatementsTable extends Component // parent
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.statements-table', [
            'statements' => Statement::limit(10)->get()
        ]);
    }
}
```

The parent `statements-table.blade`

```
<table class="table">
    @foreach($statements as $statement)
        @livewire('statement-line', ['statement' => $statement], key($statement->id))
    @endforeach
</table>
```

The child component:

```
class StatementLine extends Component
{
    public $statement;
    public $calls = 0;

    public function childMethod()
    {
        $this->calls += 1;
    }

    public function mount($statement): void
    {
        $this->statement = $statement;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.statement-line');
    }
}
```

The child `statement-line.blade`

```
{{-- dd(get_defined_vars()) --}}
<tr>
    <td>{{$statement->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$statement->date}}</td>
    <td>{{$calls}}</td>
    <td><button wire:click="childMethod">Plus</button></td>
</tr>
```

Why do I get

```
Livewire\Exceptions\MethodNotFoundException
Unable to call component method. Public method [childMethod] not found on component: [statements-table]
```

Comment: @PaulH I am encountering this issue as well.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem. The solution was:

Make sure the child's view has ONE root element as indicated in [Livewire Docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#render-method).

Comment: Altough this is very important indeed, that is not the reason of the issue. The single root element of the parent is <table> and the single root element of the child is <tr>

Answer (score 0):

You can scope your callbacks in livewire have a look at the documentation available here https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#scoping-events

For your case you should scope to self like this

```
<button wire:click="$emitSelf('childMethod')">
```

Answer (score 0):

for passing parameters (string) in a function make sure you are  using single `''` quotes , note double qoutes `""`. like :

```
wire:click="activeTab('product')"
```